# Superman given a stroke -- how could this happen?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, powers, telekinesis

Looking at [Manchester Black's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Black), I see that via telekinesis he gave Superman a stroke. I assert that, while bathed by a yellow Sun, Superman could not suffer ill effects even from interruption of blood flow; also, as even a bullet could not penetrate his eye, it seems that no force exerted to stop blood flow.

Was this addressed? How did Superman recover?

Comment: Considering how the rest of the fight played out - with Supes playing the Elite like a fiddle the whole time - it's plausible that he was faking the stroke to make them think they had the upper hand.

Comment: You can assert it all you like, but the comic shows otherwise

Comment: He always overshoots the green.

Comment: In the DCAU, Superman got sick when he was infected with a disease that only killed men. Also, in DCeased, Superman got infected and turned into a zombie. Both were at their normal level of power.

Answer (score 7):

You're referring to a scene from *[Action Comics Vol. 1 775](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_775)*. In this issue, Manchester Black used his telekinesis to manipulate the capillaries in Superman's brain, causing him to experience stroke-like symptoms. Not long after, Superman recovered sufficiently to defeat that team of metahumans, known as [the Elite](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Elite_(New_Earth)), presumably thanks to his enhanced healing capabilities.

> MANCHESTER BLACK: How's yer head? Tough. Little tubes of concrete... but the capillaries in your brain are still vulnerable to telekinesis. Close to a stroke, what you're feeling now. You're forgetting words. Reliving life experiences. Smells. Random tastes.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Action Comics Vol. 1 #775* (March, 2001)</sub>

Regarding your assertion that Superman *"could not suffer ill effects even from interruption of blood flow"*, that's seemingly disproven by this issue. It'd be fair to question it if you know of evidence to the contrary, but you didn't cite any, and in lieu of that, then this evidence is all we have to go on, and we should base our conclusions on it, rather than forming conclusions without evidence, and then rejecting any evidence that doesn't conform to those conclusions.

Likewise, regarding your assertion that *"it seems that no force exerted to stop blood flow"*, this issue clearly indicates otherwise. One could question how exactly that was achieved, and whether it makes any sense or not by real world standards. But ultimately, there's nothing remotely unusual about comicbook characters using powers with largely unexplained and seemingly unrealistic properties. Giving stuff like this a pass goes with the territory of reading superhero comics.

Regarding the question of whether Superman can *"survive without breathing indefinitely"*, it was repeatedly indicated within this specific continuity -- the [Post-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Post-Crisis)/[New Earth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Earth) continuity -- that Superman did require oxygen, although he could hold his breath for an hour or more when needed.

> LANA LANG: ... You're leaving Earth? How will you survive in space?
>
> SUPERMAN: I'll manage with this breathing apparatus a friend gave me.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Adventures of Superman Vol. 1 #450](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adventures_of_Superman_Vol_1_450)* (January, 1989)</sub>

> AQUAMAN: How long did you say you could hold your breath?
>
> SUPERMAN: Don't worry, I won't have to. I came prepared.
>
> AQUAMAN: To go after me, I suppose.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Superman: The Man of Steel Vol. 1 #48](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_The_Man_of_Steel_Vol_1_48)* (September, 1995)</sub>

Comment: Can't Superman survive without breathing indefinitely? If so, I assert that his cells do not require oxygen -- the yellow sun provides all the energy his neurons in particular need.

Comment: The answer to that question may vary depending on which version of Superman you're talking about. The Superman of this era -- often referred to as the Post-Crisis Superman -- was indicated to require oxygen. He could hold his breath for an hour or more if needed, but was repeatedly shown to use an oxygen mask when operating in space or underwater. I'll add relevant citations to my answer within the next few hours.

Comment: Wow, that is a pretty severe limitation on Superman: a normal human can hold their breath for a minute or so and longer if trained; that Superman can only do so 60 times longer than a human is incredible and would make him vulnerable to, for example, maybe carbon monoxide poisoning or maybe nitrogen. Very strange.

Comment: Some issues indicated that he could hold his breath for 2-3 hours. During the '60s and '70s, he was more powerful, and I'm not sure he needed oxygen at all. But in the mid-'80s, DC rebooted his continuity and scaled back his powers. As a result of his reduced lung capacity and flight speed, he could no longer travel interstellar distances without outside assistance, and his stories became more Earth-focused. Around the year 2000 though, there was a storyline where he trained underwater to increase his lung capacity, and he regained the ability to traverse interstellar distances without help.

Comment: I guess I did not go far enough in school to ever fully understand Superman. If one attempts to travel interstellar distances without a spacecraft, breathing would be the least of the challenges you would face, IMHO.

Comment: You may be trying too hard to square comicbook physics with real world physics, which I personally find to be a fruitless endeavour. Silver Age Superman comics in particular were about as realistic as Looney Tunes cartoons.

Comment: Which is to say, not very? I recall Roger seeing birds instead of stars or vice versa in Who Framed Roger Rabbit and assuring the director he could see the right objects if they did another take -- could he really??